# Magento 2 : Get Category Attribute Value By Option Id

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, option

How to get category attribute value by option id in magento 2.

Thanks

Comment: Which option ID? is it custom attribute?

Comment: @KeyurShah please find this link https://prnt.sc/i8p7tj

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code custom Category Attribute Value By Option Id:

```
$optionArray = [];
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$attribute = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config')->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_brand');
    if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $optionArray[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        }
    }

$categoryBrandId    = $categoryObj->getData('category_brand');
$categoryBrandLabel = $optionArray[$categoryBrandId];
```

In above code:

- Replace `category_brand` with your category attribute code.
- `$categoryObj` is Categroy Object

For example purpose, I have used `ObjectManager`. you can directly create dependency for `Magento\Eav\Model\Config` class in your class constructor and use the code.

Comment: i have only brand id , so i want brand label by brand value(id)

Comment: yes but in attribute from where you are showing values in the form. you must have specified the source model for this